# Show, hide and group columns in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, grouping, html-table

I have a table and I need to group columns. How is it possible with HTML to tell if columns belong together? I've been looking at colgroup, but I don't know if that's what I need.

I need to create a function with jquery which works somehow like Microsoft Excel's group function, so I can hide unused columns and only show the relevant columns, but also the option to show the other columns.

Comment: Something like [this](http://handsontable.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the jqGrid [demos](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html). It has functionality for grouping columns and, I believe (at least for older versions) also hiding them.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this...

HTML

```
<table>

<tr>
    <td>
        First Name
    </td>
    <td>
        Middle Initial
    </td>
    <td>
        Last Name
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        John
    </td>
    <td>
        C
    </td>
    <td>
        Doe
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Jim
    </td>
    <td>
        D
    </td>
    <td>
        Doe
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Jane
    </td>
    <td>
        E
    </td>
    <td>
        Doe
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<a  onclick="javascript:hideColumn('first')">Hide First Name</a>
<a  onclick="javascript:hideColumn('middle')">Hide Middle Initial</a>
<a  onclick="javascript:hideColumn('last')">Hide Last Name</a>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hideColumn(column) {
    var row = [];
    var dataCell = [];
    switch (column) {
        case 'first': {
            var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
            if(a[0].innerHTML == "Hide First Name")
            {
                row = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
                for(var i = 0; i < row.length; i++){
                    dataCell = row[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
                    dataCell[0].style.visibility = "hidden";    
                }
                a[0].innerHTML = "Show First Name";
            }
            else
            {
                row = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
                for(var i = 0; i < row.length; i++){
                    dataCell = row[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
                    dataCell[0].style.visibility = "visible";   
                }
                a[0].innerHTML = "Hide First Name";
            }
            break;
        }
        case 'middle': {
            var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
            if(a[1].innerHTML == "Hide Middle Initial")
            {
                row = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
                for(var i = 0; i < row.length; i++){
                    dataCell = row[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
                    dataCell[1].style.visibility = "hidden";    
                }
                a[1].innerHTML = "Show Middle Initial";
            }
            else
            {
                row = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
                for(var i = 0; i < row.length; i++){
                    dataCell = row[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
                    dataCell[1].style.visibility = "visible";   
                }
                a[1].innerHTML = "Hide Middle Initial";
            }
            break;
        }
        case 'last': {
            var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
            if(a[2].innerHTML == "Hide Last Name")
            {
                row = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
                for(var i = 0; i < row.length; i++){
                    dataCell = row[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
                    dataCell[2].style.visibility = "hidden";    
                }
                a[2].innerHTML = "Show Last Name";
            }
            else
            {
                row = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
                for(var i = 0; i < row.length; i++){
                    dataCell = row[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
                    dataCell[2].style.visibility = "visible";   
                }
                a[2].innerHTML = "Hide Last Name";
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Since you want to group items by the columns they are in, they will always be in the same spot in the row. There is probably a better/less hardcoded way to do this. But hopefully this example will help.